# How to run ipython with pypy?

Tags: python, ipython, pypy

How do I use ipython on top of a pypy interpreter rather than a cpython interpreter?  ipython website just says it works, but is scant on the details of how to do it.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can create a PyPy virtualenv :

```
virtualenv -p /path/to/pypy <venv_dir>
```

Activate the virtualenv

```
source <venv_dir>/bin/activate
```

and install ipython

```
pip install ipython
```

Comment: If someone wants to get this working on pypy for python 2, you need `pip install ipython==1.2.1`

Answer (score 5):

This worked for me, after pypy is installed:

```
pypy -m easy_install ipython
```

Then it gets installed in the same directory as pypy, so if pypy is at this location:

```
which pypy
/usr/local/bin/pypy
```

Then ipython will be there

```
/usr/local/bin/ipython
```

You can set up an alias in your bash startup script:

```
alias pypython="/usr/local/share/pypy/ipython"
```

Answer (score 4):

- install setuptools to pypy
- install pip with setuptools to pypy

do

```
pypy\bin\pip install ipython
```

Answer (score 2):

The "straight forward" way is:

1. Install `pypy3`
2. `pypy3 -m pip install ipython`
3. `pypy3 -m IPython`

Comment: pypy doesn't come with a pip installation by default (although, these days `ensurepip` could be used to bootstrap one).

Comment: Depends how you install it. For example if you install pypy through Homebrew (on macOS), then it does comes with pip pre-installed.